# How to get rid of the "Failed to resolve component: XXX" for web components with Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, web-component

Similar questions have been asked already but I still can't get rid of this warning in the browser console:

> Failed to resolve component: lottie-player
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

event though I added `app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.includes("-");`. I also tried `app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.startsWith("lottie");`but doesn't work either.

Here is my main.ts file where I mount my app :

```html
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import useDriveStore from "./DriveStore";
import App from "./components/App.vue";
import FolderView from "./views/FolderView.vue";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound.vue";

// Define routes
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        redirect: { name: "myDrive" },
    },
    {
        path: "/my-drive",
        name: "myDrive",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/recent",
        name: "recent",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/clients",
        name: "clients",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/starred",
        name: "starred",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/invoices",
        name: "invoices",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/signed",
        name: "signed",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/penelop",
        name: "penelop",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/trash",
        name: "trash",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/storage",
        name: "storage",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/folders/:uid",
        name: "folder",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/search",
        name: "search",
        component: FolderView,
    },
    {
        path: "/404",
        name: "404",
        component: NotFound,
    },
    { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*", name: "NotFound", component: NotFound }, // 404
];

// Create the router instance and pass the `routes` option
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes: routes,
});

// Create and mount the root instance.
const app = createApp(App);

// Register plugins
app.use(router);
app.use(createPinia());

// app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.startsWith("lottie");
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.includes("-");
// app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => /^x-/.test(tag);

// Add the window object to app config
app.config.globalProperties.window = window;

app.config.performance = true;

app.config.globalProperties.msg = "Boss!";

app.config.warnHandler = (msg, instance, trace) => {
    console.warn("APP CONFIG warnHandler", msg, instance, trace);
};

app.mount("#app");

const store = useDriveStore();

app.config.errorHandler = (err: Error, instance, info) => {
    console.log("APP CONFIG errorHandler", err, instance, info);

    store.setIsLoading(false);
    store.addError(err);
    store.setIsDown(true);
};
```

Here is the vue file in which I include the web component :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { watch } from "vue";

import useDriveStore from "../../DriveStore";
import TheModal from "../../../../vue/components/utilities/TheModal.vue";
import PrimaryButton from "../../../../vue/components/utilities/PrimaryButton.vue";

const store = useDriveStore();

watch(() => store.modals.kyc, (newVal) => {
    if (newVal === true) {
        setTimeout(() => store.setShowKycModal(false), 5000);
    }
});
</script>

<template>
    <Teleport to="body">
        <TheModal :show="store.modals.kyc" @close="store.setShowKycModal(false)">
            <template #header>KYC</template>
            <template #default>
                <div class="tw-text-center">
                    <lottie-player
                        src="https://assets8.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_jukns3ht.json"
                        background="transparent"
                        speed="1"
                        style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
                        loop
                        autoplay
                    ></lottie-player>
                    <p>L'analyse de votre document est en cours.</p>
                    <p class="tw-mb-10">Ce processus peut durer plusieurs minutes.</p>
                    <PrimaryButton @click="store.setShowKycModal(false)">Fermer</PrimaryButton>
                </div>
            </template>
        </TheModal>
    </Teleport>
</template>
```